# Python how to get arguments from specific string

Tags: python, string, input

i'm doing school project which is calculator of complex numbers. I wrote a function to calculate it but i dont know how to slice input string to make single arguments from it.

It looks like this:

```
in1: [complex(1.0, 1.0), complex(1.0, 1.0), ’*’, False, ’nazwa’]

in2: [complex(1 , 1), 2, ’+’, True, ’test’]
```

Its first number, second, operation, and two other arguments. I would like to slice it like:enter code here

```
number1 = 1.0,1.0
number2 = 1.0,1.0
operation = *
```

and 2 others.
I tried input().split() but it splits it like this : [(complex(1.0 | 1.0) | '*' etc.

Comment: Input is a list, Right? why do you need to split it? just access it using index.

Answer (score 1):

```
input1 = [complex(1.0, 1.0), complex(1.0, 1.0), '*', False, 'nazwa']
number1 = input1[0]
number2 = input1[1]
noperation = input1[2]
```

etc

Comment: Thanks mate, i didn't know it was so simple :) I tried couple times input().split() and it didn't worked for me :D

Comment: okey, it works if I write it like this but I want to have it that I can input multiple strings myself by function input() or something

Answer (score 0):

You can use, input1[index] = input("Your message here")
You can also cast the input too into the primitive type you want, such as,
input1[index] = int(input("Your message here"))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you expand your answer to include a properly formatted code sample and perhaps a link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: `def CKalkulator(number1, number2, operation, ifplot, name):

    liczba1 = number1
    liczba2 = number2
    znak = operation
    graf = ifplot
   

    if znak == '+':
        wynik = liczba1 + liczba2
    elif znak == '-':
        wynik = liczba1 - liczba2
    elif znak == '*':
        wynik = liczba1 * liczba2
    elif znak == '/':
        wynik = liczba1 / liczba2`
This function also is making plot with matplotlib and other operations.